# clock() works well on debug version but won't work on release (C++ VS2010)

Tags: c++, timer, release, clock

This is my code:

```
// Start performance test clock
assert((start=clock())!=-1);

// Some reading and writing methods

// Get stop time
stop = clock();

cout << stop << endl;

// Calculate operation time
double result = (double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

// Print result
cout << "--> Finished analysing in " << result << "s" << endl;
```

It works great when I debug my program, but when I run the release version, 
stop receives a much smaller value than start, and result is a negative number.

Any ideas?

Comment: The release version may be heavily optimized and thus it takes much less time than in the debug version. Usually, debug versions don't use optimization. What happens if you disable optimization in the release configuration (be sure to re-enable it afterwards)?

Comment: @WTP: I doubt any compiler can optimize code so well that it can travel back in time! The problem was not just getting a smaller value for time, but getting a negative value.

Comment: Aside: Consider using the [Boost timer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/timer/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The assignment of `start` should not be in the `assert` statement.  `assert` is typically a no-op in release builds.  So in the debug build, the statement `start=clock()` would be executed, but in the release build, it would not.  So it is possible (depending on earlier code and the declaration of `start`) that it is not initialized.  It is typically desirable to avoid using `assert` statements that have side effects; it can lead to subtle differences/bugs between debug and release builds.

It might be better to write it like this:

```
start = clock();
assert(start != -1);
```